# Where to define the model for the view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I looked at some Views from Backbone.js, but i don't see at which point it is declared which model is binded to the view ?

For example here where does the view defines which model is `this.model` ?
https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/views/todos.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a `model` property in the options argument to the View's constructor, Backbone automatically sets it as `view.model`:

```
var someModel = new Model();
var view = new View({model:someModel});
console.log(view.model === someModel); // -> true
```

This feature is [documented here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

> When creating a new View, the options you pass — after being merged into any default options already present on the view — are attached to the view as this.options for future reference. There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: **model**, collection, el, id, className, tagName and attributes.

In the Todolist example the model is set in [app.js, line 75](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/views/app.js).

```
addOne: function( todo ) {
  var view = new TodoView({ model: todo });
  $('#todo-list').append( view.render().el );
},
```